# Does autofocus work with the Pentax K10D and Tamron 18-250mm?

Tags: focus, pentax, tamron, superzoom

Hallo; does autofocus actually work with the Pentax K10D and Tamron 18-250mm?

If so,how good/fast is it?

Comment: Can you be more specific as to the lens? Some Tamron 18-250s have in-built motors, some don't.

Answer (score 1):

If the [version of the firmware](http://www.pentax.jp/english/support/digital/k10d_s.html) on your K10D is at least 1.30, then autofocus will operate with all K-mount variants of the lens.  If not, variants of the lens that do not have an AF coupler at the lens mount (if they exist for the K mount) will not be able to autofocus.